# Change object references in eclipse during debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, object, variable-assignment

During an Eclipse debugger session in the eclipse debugging view, it is possible to change arbitrary primitive variables and even Strings.

I wonder why it does not seem possible to change variable references to objects as well.
E.g. if there is something like

```
 ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader()
```

in the code I'd like to be able to bind the variable ("change its value" in a relaxed sense) to

```
 cl = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader
```

during debugging.

Am I wrong (it is possible to do this) and if not, are there any conceptional reasons (so other reasons than "nobody simply has done this yet")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It transpires that you can actually do this in a round about way.  Code:-

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestDebug {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    Object foo = new Object();
    System.err.println(foo);
  }
}
```

Breakpoint on the syserr line.

Select 'this' in the variables view then type into the details area at the bottom the following code:-

foo = new java.util.ArrayList()

Now select the above expression and hit shift+ctrl+i (inspect) and it will execute the code.  Lo and behold foo now contains an array list!

Comment: Very nice, didn't know about this one...
Now, is there a way to do the same in a static context (i.e. when there is no "this")?

Comment: OK, I found a way to do it:
Select the (static) object that needs to be changed (in the Variables view).
Use the detail area to define a new expression:
* just that new expression without an assignment
* no trailing semicolon
* fully qualified name
e.g. new java.util.LinkedList()
Then, use the Assign Value option from the context menu (right click into the details area).

Answer (score 2):

You can manually [execute any piece of Java code](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-debug_view.htm) in a suspended thread in the debugger, including assignments to all variables or fields which are visible in the context of the current stack frame.

So yes, that assignment should be possible.

Comment: Thanks Bananeweizen, your answer is valid as well but I chose Mumrah's as accepted because he was first and had a detailed example.